# How to reproduce predict.svm() in R when doing regression?

Tags: r, regression, svm, predict

I have trained a svm model in R using eps-regression and a radial kernel in the e1017 package. I can make predictions for new observations when using the function predict() but I'm interested in reproducing this outside a R environment. To do so I need to know how does R predict new observations.

There is an example of how to do so when using svm to do classification ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375072/how-to-reproduce-predict-svm-in-r?rq=1)) but it doesn't work when doing regression due to the fact that the predictive function has a different formula:
In the case of classification the predictive function is given by

```
$\hat{f}(x)= \sum^N_{i=1} \hat{\alpha}_i y_i K(x,x_i)+\hat{\beta}_0 $,
```

where $y_i$ is already contained in m$coefs

whereas in the case of regression the predictive function is given by

```
$\hat{f}(x)= \sum^N_{i=1} \hat{\alpha}_i K(x,x_i) $
```

both formulas according to Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman (2001).

I have also read [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2002/Heidelberg02/moldiag-svm.pdf) that \hat{\alpha}_i are the support vectors so I tried to use them in my predictive function, instead of the coeficients used in the classification case.

As an example one could use:

```
library(e1071)

x <- seq(0.1, 5, by = 0.05) 
y <- log(x) + rnorm(x, sd = 0.2)

m   <- svm(y~x) 
new <- predict(m, x)

k<-function(x,x1,gamma){   
   return(exp(-gamma*sum((x-x1)^2))) }

f<-function(x,m){   
   return(t(m$SV) %*% as.matrix(apply(m$SV,1,k,x,m$gamma))) }

my.predict<-function(m,x){   
            apply(x,1,f,m)}

x<-as.matrix(x) 
my.predict(m,x)[1:10]
new[1:10]
```

Can someone explain where is this going wrong and/or recommend literature on the subject?

Thanks,
Marta

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
library(e1071)

x <- seq(0.1, 5, by = 0.05)
y <- log(x) + rnorm(x, sd = 0.2)
m   <- svm(y~x,scale=F,kernel="radial")
k<-function(x,x1,gamma){
  return(exp(-gamma*(x-x1)^2))
}
f<-function(x,m,xi){
  return(apply(xi,1,function(z) t(m$coefs) %*% (k(m$SV,z,m$gamma))))
}

my.predict<-function(m,x,xi){
  xi<-as.matrix(xi)
  return(f(x,m,xi)-m$rho)
}
my.predict(m,x,x)[1:10] 
new <- predict(m, x)
new[1:10]
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to do this for multivariate data? I tried this method with data with more than one features and the results were different. Thanks!