# Reproducing predict function in the svm method in R

Tags: r, svm, predict

I want to reproduce predict function in R. I found very nice example here [How to reproduce predict.svm in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375072/how-to-reproduce-predict-svm-in-r/14380424#14380424), but it does not work on my data.
The difference is that I have four classes.

I receive error "Error in x - x1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator". After advice from MrFlick, I add as.numeric to all values (this change the error, so I check my original data table, and there where few non numeric values).

Right now, I have another error: "Error in f(y, m) : dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [6]"

My data are big, so I prepared some values to show you my problem.

```
library(e1071)
Cval =100
GammaVal=0.1 

sp1a<-as.numeric(c("2.58","0","0","10.85","20.1","0","0","0","0","0","76.03","0","0","28.79","0","2.76","0","0","23.99","0"))
sp1b<-as.numeric(c("135.32","133.82","134.24","132.84","135.11","133.55","132.99","130.25","133.19","132.42","135.8","133.99","133.33","135.52","134.67","134.79","134.32","133.9","135.36","133.14"))
sp1c<-as.numeric(sp1b)/2.3
sp1d<-as.numeric(sp1b)-3.5
sp1e<-as.numeric(sp1a)+1.3
sp1f<-as.numeric(sp1a)*2
  
data<-data.frame(cbind(sp1a,sp1b,sp1c,sp1d,sp1e,sp1f,class=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,6))))
svm_mod = svm(class~.,type="C-classification",data=data,cost = Cval, gamma = GammaVal,cross=10)
summary(svm_mod) 
svm_train_pred = predict(svm_mod, data)
self_check_svm_out = cbind(data,svm_train_pred)
tab <- table(pred = svm_train_pred, true = data[,7]) 

## my predict functions
k<-function(x,x1,gamma){
  return(exp(-gamma*sum((x-x1)^2)))
}

f<-function(x,m){
  return(t(m$coefs) %*% as.matrix(apply(m$SV,1,k,x,m$gamma)) - m$rho)
}

my.predict<-function(m,x){
  apply(x,1,function(y) sign(f(y,m)))
}

table(my.predict(svm_mod,data[,1:4]),predict(svm_mod,data[,1:4]))
```

Comment: Why are your `sp1a` and `sp1b` values character values rather than numeric values? Did you want to model them as categorical variables?

Comment: To be honest, I want to prepare some data sample, do I didn't think on that. I cbind them later to a data.frame. I will ad as.numeric to the examples

Comment: Thank you very much, MrFlick. This help, but I have other problem. I edited the question to this.